# Rotating image to Mobile's Orientation when capturing with camera :Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera, image-rotation

I am building an Android application where I click a photograph from my mobile's camera and display it in a ImageView it automatically gets rotated by 90 degrees counter-clockwise.I want to display it in the orientation in which it is clicked by the mobile rather than letting it to be rotated.

Could anyone provide with relevant code snippets or pointers to some relevant documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Check [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html)

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFilePath);
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

switch(orientation) {
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
    // rotate the image
    break;

    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this methoh It will help you.

```
/*   
 * 1 = Horizontal (normal) 
 * 2 = Mirror horizontal 
 * 3 = Rotate 180 
 * 4 = Mirror vertical 
 * 5 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 270 CW 
 * 6 = Rotate 90 CW 
 * 7 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 90 CW 
 * 8 = Rotate 270 CW
 */
public static Bitmap getRotateBitmapImage(Bitmap bm, int newHeight,int newWidth, int exifOrientation) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    switch (exifOrientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotate = 270;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotate = 180;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotate = 90;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
        rotate = 45;
        break;
    case 0:
        rotate = 360;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    matrix.postRotate(rotate);
    // resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 65, 65, true);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: I am using the Intenet xyz = new Intent(Mediastore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) to capture the image. What format does this store in and how can i pass the object of the image captured here to the function you described here? How about the new height, new Width ?

Comment: you can just ignore the newHeight and newWitdh part if you are not scaling the bitmap. just use the bitmap.getWidth() and bitmap.getHeight().

Comment: You can remove new height/width at the time of Bitmap.createBitmap